# ENOENT with 'a+' mode

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var date = new Date();
var logPath = __dirname + '/log/transcript.' + date.getUTCHours() + ':' + date.getUTCMinutes() + ':' + date.getUTCSeconds() + '.' + date.getUTCDate() + '-' + date.getUTCMonth() + '-' + date.getUTCFullYear() + '.log';

var logger = {
    deglog: function (degree, value) {
        var now = new Date().toUTCString();

        stream = fs.createWriteStream(logPath, {
            'flags': 'a+',
            'encoding': 'utf8'
        });

        stream.write(now + ' ');
        stream.write(degree + ': ');
        stream.write(value + '\n');

        stream.end();
    },
    log: function (value) {
        this.deglog('INFO', value);
    },
    warning: function (value) {
        this.deglog('WARN', value);
    },
    error: function (value) {
        this.deglog('ERROR', value);
    }
}
```

Above snippet is supposed to be creating a file if it doesn't exist, yet I get an ENOENT error. Can anyone explain the issue to me?

Comment: Please show us the exact error message

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/lGHtTnM.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error isn't related to using the flag, it's just that you have illegal characters in your file name. Get rid of them and it will work properly.

```
transcript.6:25:16.13-9-2013.log
            │  │
            └──└── illegal characters
```

Answer (score 0):

@hexacyanide is correct that you have an illegal char in your filename. But, also you can catch uncaught exceptions and log them for better debugging down the line.

```
process.on('uncaughtException',function(err) { console.log(err.stack); ... });
```